# Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am using sharepoint online trying to create a web site as an app, but getting the above error.

Then i tried the below in SharePoint online management script as mentioned on one of the sites

```
Enable-SPFeature e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085 –url http://sp.contoso.com
```

which gives me this error

> "The term 'Enable-SPFeature' is not recognized' as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also having same issue. I used SharePoint Online Management Shell and took the following approach:-

**Solution-1**

I guess you are not running your SharePoint Online Management Shell as Administrator or else you are not including **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll** before running the Command.

**Solution-2:**

You can use below script in **SharePoint Online Management Shell**, make sure you run your **SharePoint Online Management Shell** as Administrator.

```
$programFiles = [environment]::getfolderpath("programfiles")
add-type -Path $programFiles'\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Write-Host 'Insert information for Site'
$siteurl = Read-Host "Site Url"
$username = Read-Host "User Name"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Password"

try
{
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$ClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)
    $ClientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
    $site = $ClientContext.Site;

    $sideLoadingGuid = new-object System.Guid "AE3A1339-61F5-4f8f-81A7-ABD2DA956A7D"
    $site.Features.Add($sideLoadingGuid, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None);

    $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'SideLoading feature enabled :)'
}
catch
{ 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Error ' $siteurl, ':' $Error[0].ToString();
}
```

Both approach helped me to resolve the Error.

I found this script [here](http://www.emanuelebartolesi.com/en/post/enable-sideloading-on-a-sharepoint-office-365-site)

Comment: Thanks Aakash, on solution 1 : i run the SharePoint Online Management Shell as administrator but like benny said Enable-SPFeature will not work with online. can you tell me how to run the script you provided in solution 2 ? . i replaced the site url, username ,  Password with my own. and copied and pasted the whole code and hit enter. But it is not the way  should i save the file with some extention and then run it  ?

Comment: nope it still shows the same i enable it using the above mentioned details. but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Create a *.ps1 file and copy paste above script with credentials and run it from SharePoint Online Management Shell. This is working script I have been using it from very long past

Comment: I have done that already Aakash and i got the message sideloading feature enabled. but on the VS is showing the same error as before.

Comment: Lastly verify you are running your Visual Studio in Administrator mode or with Valid user logged in

Comment: It works Aakash there was a whitespace in URL causes the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

It means that you can't use SharePoint Server cmdlet on SharePoint Online environment. Every SharePoint Online cmdlet has the "word" SPO in it. Enable-SPFeature is for SharePoint Server only.

- [Enable-SPFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx)
- [Index of Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/fp161364(v=office.15).aspx)

However, I learnt today, you can use PowerShell and CSOM:

> ## Using PowerShell
>
> One way would be to install the excellent (and free!) [SharePoint Client Browser for SharePoint 2010 and 2013](http://spcb.codeplex.com/).  It includes an extremely useful feature to open up PowerShell with the CSOM already loaded.
>
> [image]
>
> Using that PowerShell window, you could then easily use the client
> side object model (CSOM) to enable the developer feature.
>
> ```
> $ctx.Load($ctx.Site);
> $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
> $guid = [System.Guid]"e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085"
> $ctx.Site.Features.Add($guid,$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None)
> $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
> ```
>
> Too easy.

Reference: [Enabling the Developer Site Collection Feature in SharePoint Online](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/10/05/enabling-the-developer-site-collection-feature-in-sharepoint-online/)

> ## Do you have one of the following Office 365 subscription plans?
>
> - Office 365 Midsize Business
> - Office 365 Enterprise E1, E3, E4, E5, or
> - K1 Office 365 Education A2, A3, or A4
> - Office 365 Government G1, G3, G4, or K1

Reference: [Set up a development environment for SharePoint Add-ins on Office 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924.aspx)

Comment: did a bit of googleing and found the same but now ends up having another problem. Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@contoso.com. When i tried the above code it give be an error saying current site is not a tenant administrative site.

Comment: may i ask what is the equivalent for Enable-SPFeature ? coz i have some trouble finding it from the list

Comment: @Rinu There is none implemented yet, so you need to activate the feature from site settings > manage site features (or manage web features)

Comment: which feature benny

Comment: @Rinu The Developer Site Collection Feature. See my updated answer where you actually can enable the feature from PowerShell with CSOM using a tool. Thanks for asking this question. I've never lernt this otherwise :-)

Comment: ya Benny it works this way as well but i am still getting the same error while trying to update. The site URL property in VS I mentioned the the site collection URL not the mysite-admin.sharepoint.com. I used to have a lots of confusion with this regards as a complete newbie with this

Comment: @Rinu Maybe you don't have the correct subscription plan? See the updated answer.

Comment: It shouldnt be a problem we have E4 Benny

Comment: @Rinu In that case, your only option is to contact Microsoft Support från your tennant. They are fast and accurate. Good luck

Comment: It works Benny some white space in the URL causes the problem :)